# Representing a 16 byte variable

Tags: c++

I have to represent a 16 byte field as part of a data structure:

```
struct Data_Entry
{
    uint8   CUI_Type;
    uint8   CUI_Size;
    uint16  Src_Refresh_Period;
    uint16  Src_Buffer_Size;
    uint16  Src_CUI_Offset;
    uint32  Src_BCW_Address;
    uint32  Src_Previous_Timestamp;
    /* The field below should be a 16 byte field */
    uint32      Data;

};
```

How would I represent the "Data" field as a 16 byte field instead of the 4 byte field it currently is?

Thanks,

Bobby

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything wrong with `uint8 Data[16];`?

Answer (score 8):

Use an array:

```
struct Data_Entry
{
    uint8   CUI_Type;
    uint8   CUI_Size;
    uint16  Src_Refresh_Period;
    uint16  Src_Buffer_Size;
    uint16  Src_CUI_Offset;
    uint32  Src_BCW_Address;
    uint32  Src_Previous_Timestamp;
    /* The field below should be a 16 byte field */
    uint32  Data[4];

};
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a hard time to believe you want this 16byte field to be a scalar integer.
In the odd event that int16B is what you want (for a fotonic enumerator application, observing the universe), you need to define it as a class, make appropriate storage (see below), overload every arithmetic operators, to make any good use of it.

If you want a set of 16 bytes under the same name, to which arithmetic wont be applied, use

```
uint8 Data[16];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one these:
  `uint8 Data[16];`
or
  `uint16 Data[8];`
or
  `uint32 Data[4];`
or
  `uint64 Data[2];  // uint64 may not be available on all platforms`

Or you could use `std::vector` instead of an array for the above.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`boost::bitset<128>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html).

Comment: @Joshua: I'm pretty sure it won't, but the question is tagged C++, not C.